# Comma concerning "in which" sentence

Tags: grammar, commas, sentence, questions

I would like to know how to set the comma(s) in this sentence?

> I visited a course in which we read the book "Heart of Darkness" approaching topics such as imperialism and eurocentrism.

Comment: I would take a comma before the closing quote mark, to set off the *approaching* phrase. Not sure if the course was doing the approaching or the book did, but someone must.

Comment: I hear a comma there, too.

Comment: But I'd prefer two or zero.

Comment: I took a course in which we read *Heart of Darkness*, a book approaching topics such as imperialism and eurocentrism.